# Linear congruence fill in the missing step?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, divisibility, congruences

Currently working on this problem and I'm having trouble seeing how it goes from one line to the next.

$45x \equiv 63\mod 11$ goes to $x \equiv 8\mod 11$

[image]

Any help would be awesome thanks.

Please try to explain how it works to help me see thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The intuition is that one can replace an argument of a sum or product by any congruent integer (not true for exponents!). This follows by the [Polynomial Congruence Rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242), i.e. by iterating the congruence Sum and Product rules. Let's do this very carefully for your example.

Note that $\ \ \color{#c00}{45\equiv 1}\pmod{11}\ $ by $\ 11\mid 45\!-\!1 = 44$

Therefore $\ \color{#c00}{45}x\equiv \color{#c00}1x\equiv x\,$ by the [Congruence Product Rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242).

Similarly $\ \ \color{#0a0}{63\equiv 8}\pmod{11}\ $ by $\ 11\mid 63\!-\!8 = 55.\ $  Chaining together these congruence equations

$\qquad x\equiv \color{#c00}1x\equiv\color{#c00}{45}x \equiv \color{#0a0}{63 \equiv 8}\,$ so $\,x\equiv 8\,$ since $\,\equiv\,$ is *transitive*, being an [equivalence relation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation).

Answer (score 0):

As $45\equiv1\pmod{11}\implies45x\equiv x\pmod{11}$

and $63\equiv8$